# PHP format an array of arrays into a flat array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an generated array into this format and want to generated a second array to fit into a file that expects the specific format

This is the array i have :

```
(int) 0 => array(
        [Service] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6948229
            [document] => Array
                (
                    [number] => 0003928425
                )
        )
```

This is the array i want to build from the previous array (will have many indexes)

```
verified[id]
verified[number]
```

So far i build this script:

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value )
        {
            echo '<br>key '.$key;
            foreach($value as $k=>$v)
            {
                $Verified[$key]['id'] = $v["id"];
                $Verified[$key]['number'] = $v['document']['number'];
```

But just get undefined index error message.

Which indexes i must use to get the flatten array ?

Comment: Try using `echo 'ID: '.$service['id'];` and 
`echo 'Number: '.$service['document']['number'];`

Comment: I think there is no need of second foreach try your code removing second foreach.

Comment: Sorry i update the array format it starts on the index 0 and so on   : (int) 0 => array(
        [Service] => Array
        (

Comment: The message is  undefined variable for echo 'ID: '.$service['id'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can make from your question, you can do something like this to get the desired output,

```
    $Verified = []; //use array() for versions below 5.5
    foreach($data as $key=>$value )
            {
                echo '<br>key '.$key;
                foreach($value as $k=>$v)
                {   
                    if(is_array($v)){
                        $Verified[$key]['number'] = $v['document']['number'];
                    }
                    $Verified[$key]['id'] = $v['id'];
```

Comment: are there more elements in the array and does the 'document' array structure change in other elements of the array? where exactly are you getting undefined index..can you post it here please.

Comment: Now it works i have more indexes other than service so i add if($k=='Service') and it works, now i have a flatten array ready to return from the method. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please pass your array to this function

```js
function arrayconvert($arr) {
  if (is_array($arr)) {
    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
      if (is_array($v)) {
        arrayconvert($v);
      } else {
        $newarr[$k] = $v;
      }
    }
  }

  return $newarr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of second foreach and you are getting undefined index because you are using `$v['id']` insted of `$val['id']` in that line `$Verified[$key]['id'] = $v["id"];`

```
<?php 
$data = array('Service' => array('id' => 6948229,'document' => array ('number' => '0003928425' )));
$verified = array();
foreach($data as $key => $val)
{ 
    $verified[$key]['id'] = $val['id'];     
    $verified[$key]['number'] = $val['document']['number'];     
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($verified);
?>
```

output

```
Array
(
    [Service] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6948229
            [number] => 0003928425
        )

)
```